# javascript eval issue (let = new Array)

Tags: javascript

Why does this work?
`eval('let = new Array')`
Please help me im confused

Tried to run it on: firefox, chrome.
Excepted result: error

Comment: How is this related to `eval`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `let` is only restricted keyword when in [*strict mode*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) [MDN source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#reserved_words):

```js
let = new Array();

console.log(let);
```

**VS**

```js
"use strict";

let = new Array();

console.log(let);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Let` is the name of variable.

Example here:

```js
let = new Array
foo = new Array
bar = new Array

console.log(let, foo, bar)
```